# How to add a button to Customer Information Tab in Magento?

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.8, observers, adminhtml

I am trying to add a button in the `Customers->Account Information` tab. I want the button to do an action when it is clicked. I would like to do this in a custom module. I'm not too fond of the idea of rewriting core files or any classes. From what I have googled people say you can do this using an `Observer`, an example is [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12413/how-can-add-a-button-for-a-particular-tab-in-the-admin-section) , if that is true then I would like to do it this way.

I know how to make a basic module, what I need help on is how do you put a button in a specific tab without rewriting the files/classes?

*Update 11/3/2013 11am:*

Here is the screenshot [image: here]

I would like to add the button on this tab.

*Update 2:48pm 11/3/2014*

Here is my code so far, maybe I am making a mistake somewhere.

**My file structure**

```
-app
    -local
        -Rdtmodules
            -ChangeGroupNotification
                -etc
                    -config.xml
                -Model
                    -Observer.php
    -etc
        -modules
            -Rdtmodules_ChangeGroupNotification.xml
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Rdtmodules_ChangeGroupNotification>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Rdtmodules_ChangeGroupNotification>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <rdtmodules_changegroupnotification>
                    <class>Rdtmodules_ChangeGroupNotification_Model</class>
                </rdtmodules_changegroupnotification>
            </models>
            <events>
                <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                    <observers>
                        <rdtmodules_changegroupnotification>
                            <class>rdtmodules_changegroupnotification/observer</class>
                            <method>sendCustomerGroupChangeNotification</method>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                        </rdtmodules_changegroupnotification>
                    </observers>
                </adminhtml_block_html_before>
            </events>
        </global>
    </config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php 

class Rdtmodules_ChangeGroupNotification_Model_Observer {
    public function sendCustomerGroupChangeNotification(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData('block');
        if($block->getId() == 'customer_edit' && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'customer_edit') {
            $block->addButton('test_print', array(
                'label'     => 'Test',
                'onclick'   =>'setLocation(\'' . $block->getUrl('html/sales_order/print') . '\')',
                'class'     => 'go'
        ));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured the problem was with my if statements since everything else was working. So first here is my code for the observer.

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Rdtmodules_GroupNotification_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendNotification(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData('block');
        if($block->getNameInLayout() == 'customer_edit' && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'customer') {
            $block->addButton('test_print', array(
                'label'     => 'Test',
                'onclick'   =>'setLocation(\'' . $block->getUrl('html/sales_order/print') . '\')',
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
    }       
}
```

the `$block->getId()` didn't return anything which is why it wasn't working. Also the controller name was not `customer_edit` it was just `customer` o.o.

How i figured this out was I printed the controller names action names and block names in the layout.

```
echo "Controller Name: " . $block->getRequest()->getControllerName();
echo "Action Name: " . $block->getRequest()->getActionName();
echo "Block Name: " . $block->getNameInLayout();
```

That is how I figured out what the problem was.

Very useful.